# How to create a node that listens to particular topic and publishes tf

Tags: ros, rviz, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I create a node that listens to that particular topic and publishes the required required tf. I have succesfully published data on a topic. Now I want to exhibit it in TF. Do I need a TF broadcaster, something like this

```
tf::TransformBroadcaster br;
tf::Transform transform;
transform.setOrigin( tf::Vector3(0,0,0)); 
transform.setRotation( tf::Quaternion(x,y,z,w) ); 
br.sendTransform(tf::StampedTransform(transform, ros::Time::now(), "optical", "base_link"));
```

Even If I have something like this. How do I listen and display it. Forexample do I need a tf listener to listen to some topic which is publishing data. If thats the case. What would the code look like if my topic is `/mytopic`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/71851/how-to-create-a-node-that-listens-to-particular-topic-and-publishes-tf/) by [micheal](https://answers.ros.org/users/5403/micheal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2013-08-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is a piece of code that publishes an odometry transform over tf.

```
void pub_odom::odom_callback(const nav_msgs::Odometry& odom) {

btVector3 Position;
btQuaternion Orientation;
tf::TransformBroadcaster odom_broadcaster_;
tf::StampedTransform odom_transform;

Position.setValue(odom.pose.pose.position.x,odom.pose.pose.position.y,odom.pose.pose.position.z);
Orientation.setW(odom.pose.pose.orientation.w);
Orientation.setX(odom.pose.pose.orientation.x);
Orientation.setY(odom.pose.pose.orientation.y);
Orientation.setZ(odom.pose.pose.orientation.z);

odom_transform.setOrigin(map_center);
odom_transform.setRotation(tf::Quaternion(tf::Vector3(0,0,1),-yaw_init));
odom_transform.stamp_ = odom.header.stamp;
odom_transform.child_frame_id_= "/odom";
odom_transform.frame_id_= "/center_map";
odom_broadcaster_.sendTransform(odom_transform);}
```

Hope it helps you

---

Originally posted by [Mario Garzon](https://answers.ros.org/users/568/mario-garzon/) with karma: 802 on 2013-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2013-08-08**:
You also could replace btVector3 and btQuaternion by tf::Vector3 and tf::Quaternion.

**Comment by [micheal](https://answers.ros.org/users/5403/micheal/) on 2013-08-10**:
@Mario Garzon Can you please send me a link to your whole  package so that I can visualise your package with tf. danke Schoen. Right now i cannot run your program so that I can understand better.